# Cannot select first name and group from DB:

Tags: php, mysqli

My code for select is this:

```
$user_check_query="SELECT first_name,group FROM users WHERE username=?";
$query=$bd->prepare($user_check_query);
$query->bind_param('s',$username);
$query->execute();
$query->bind_result($first_name,$group);
$query->fetch();
```

The error is - Fatal error: Call to a member function bind_param() on a non-object in
C:\xampp\htdocs\project1\test.php on line 9, at line 9 is the bind_param. The fields into the database are not empty and here their screenshot:
http://prikachi.com/images/786/7271786g.png
The table is users, i've checked that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

group is a reserved key word.
You need to backtic it as

```
`group`


SELECT first_name,`group` FROM users WHERE username=?
```

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/reserved-words.html